# Files on mounted disk use double space

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have two additional disks /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdc1 which are mounted on "/home/user/xxx1" and "/home/user/xxx2".
But I am surprisingly find that although the files use the space on their disk, they also use the space on my os disk /dev/sda1. So it seems they are using double space.

`du -h` give the following information:

```
/dev/sda1        16G   13G  2.6G  83% /
/dev/sdc1        20G  3.7G   15G  20% /home/user/xxx2
/dev/sdb1        20G  5.0G   14G  27% /home/user/xxx1
```

but without xxx1 and xxx2, there are only a little files on the os disk.

It's really strange, is there anybody have any idea about this question?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo du -hxd1 /`?

Comment: @muru I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I just checked `~/` but not `/`. Thank you for notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
df -h
```

It will list file systems, not partitions, so you can see an exact usage of each HDD.